# Not able to generate JWT token for python zephyr

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira, jira-zephyr

I'm unable to generate valid JWT token for the below endpoint:
https://prod-api.zephyr4jiracloud.com/connect/public/rest/api/1.0/cycle/cycleId/export?versionId=&exportType=&projectId=

I have the cycleId passed as parameter and rest query arguments too but unable to get a response.

I'm unsure about how to set the RELATVE_PATH for the above endpoint?
Example provided for python([link](https://github.com/zephyrdeveloper/zapi-cloud/blob/master/generator/python/CycleTest.py)) shows:
RELATIVE_PATH = '/public/rest/api/1.0/cycle'

Tried using RELATIVE_PATH = '/public/rest/api/1.0/cycle/ 79655-XXX-XXXX/export' but no luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this resolved by maintaining an order of query parameters. Strangely, the query params should be sorted alphabetically.
This was a hit and try based on the reference provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56169187/is-there-any-method-to-generate-qsh-value-for-jwt-token-generation-to-access-zep)